# "Kiaj" or "kiuj novaĵoj ĉe vi"?

Tags: prepositions

Which one is correct, or better, or more often used to simply ask "what's new with you" "what's up"? In my Esperanto textbook I can see "**kiaj** novaĵoj ĉe vi", but isn't "**kia**" used to ask about features, what sb/sth is *like*? And if so, why do we necessarily have to ask what new things are *like*? Can't I just ask *what* (**kiuj**) are they? In my opinion, it makes more sense, because "kiaj novaĵoj" seems to assume that there are some new things and we just ask what are they like. But what if there's nothing new? Who said there always has to be something new? More general question, *what's new with you* seems to me more logical, especially because in response I don't think I'll get a list of adjectives, but rather nouns.

Answer (score 1):

We humans tend to be imprecise, so while someone asks *kiaj novaĵoj*, the questioner does not expect a literal answer describing the guality of recent events, rather a description of the events themselves.

Having said that the more common alternatives are *kio estas nova* and even the informal *kio novas*. This kind of question belongs to spoken language, so there is almost no hits in Tekstaro. A quick googling reveals that *kiaj novaĵoj* is rare (ca. 600 hits), *kio novas* ca. 21 000 while for *kio estas nova* Google gives ca. 194 000 hits. Undoubtedly the latter figure contains cases where there is a noun directly after, but those figures should give a reasonable understanding of the order of magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

Ĉio dependas de ĝusteco de la respondo, kiun vi volas aŭdi. Kaj de via ĝusteco kaj diligenteco dum via demandado.

Vi povas demandi maldiligente "Nu, rakontu!" Aŭ eĉ "Nu?". En senco "Nu, vi rakontu kio estas nova" aŭ "kio okazis".
Kiel mi komprenas, la demando "what's up" mem signifas (sed ne laŭvorte sonas) - "Kio estas nova?" aŭ "Kio okazis?". Tamen kutimo de anglalingva medio taksas tiun demandon kiel ritan, ĝi eĉ ne postulas respondon :)

Se la demando sonas kiel "kiaj novaĵoj ĉe vi?...", do ni rajtas kompreni tion kiel reduktita de "Kiaj novaĵoj estas ĉe vi, ĉu bonaj aŭ malbonaj?". La vasta senco estas tute egala - propono ion rakonti. Ĝusta senco - nur respondi pri kvalitoj de pasintaj okazoj.

Do, atendataj estas respondoj nur "novaĵoj estas bonaj" aŭ "novaĵoj estas malbonaj". Aŭ eĉ sible "ĉio estas bone/malbone".
Se iu volas vere vastan respondon, kie novaĵoj estas priskribitaj kiel faktoj, do utilus demandi "kiuj novaĵoj..." ĉar la demandvorto "kia" estas demando pri kvalito/eco, demando "kiu" estas elektilo de io konkreta el listo (mi povas scii iujn novaĵojn eĉ sen demando, sed kiuj el ili tuŝas same mian korespondanton?). Aŭ uzi demandon kun la vorto "kio".

Ĉiuokaze tiuj demandoj havas kuntekston - inter kiuj homoj okazas la konversacio, kondiĉoj, tempo, medio inkluzive la morojn de popoloj, al kiuj apartenas la homoj ktp. Do, kompreni sencon devas per la kunteksto.
Nu?

Answer (score 0):

Miamedie ni uzas:

```
Ĉu novaĵoj?
Ĉu estas novaĵoj?
```

ĉar estas evidenta afero ke oni demandas pri novaĵoj ĉe la alparolato. Sed povus esti ankaŭ ĝeneralaj, se mi demandas tion al iu, kiu rigardas la ĵurnalon.

Ankaŭ eblas:

```
Ĉu estas novaĵoj ĉe vi?
```

Sed mi demandus

```
Kiaj/Kiuj novaĵoj ĉe vi
```

nur se mi certas pri la ekzisto de tiuj novaĵoj kaj volas (emigi) diskonigon ĉu de la listo, ĉu de ĝenerala adjektiva priskribo.

Pensi pri eblaj/celataj respondoj ankaŭ helpas decidi la ĝustan demandon:

```
Ĉu novaĵoj / ĉu estas novaĵoj ĉe vi
- Jes, mia kato ...
- Ne / Neniu
```

Kiam oni uzas `kiaj`:

```
Kiaj novaĵoj ĉe vi?
- Aĉegaj, bedaŭrinde mia hundo ...
- Bonegaj, mi vetis rete kaj ...
- Nenia(j)
```

Kun `kiuj`:

```
Kiuj novaĵoj ĉe vi?
- Mia kato ..., mia hundo ..., mi vetis ...
- Neniu(j)
```